# Construct a pure function containing built-in 'Sequence'

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, pure-function, built-in-symbols

I guessed the output for

```
 (Sequence[#, 7]&)[3]
```

should be

```
 Sequence[3,7]
```

But my guess was wrong. See the screenshot:

[image]

And I tried to construct such function as pure-function, but failed.

A workaround (not as pure-function) is `Seq[x_] := Sequence[x, 7]`

[image]

Q1) Why does the code `Sequence[#, 7]&)[3]` fail ?
Q2) Is it possible to construct such function as a pure-function ?

Comment: One possible workaround for the pure function could be `ReleaseHold@Hold[#, 7] &[3]`

Comment: The reason for this problem is because `Function` doesn't have `SequenceHold` or `HoldAllComplete` attribute, If you add it manually which is not a good idea (`SetAttributes[Function, SequenceHold]`) problem will be solved.

Comment: If Sequence appears as argument in a function: f, it splices its own arguments into f. E.g. f[Sequence[a,b]] evaluates to f[a,b]. In your case: (Sequence[#,7]) is the same as Function[Sequence[#,7]] and this evaluates to: Function[#,7]. The first argument should be a variable name and # ist not.

Comment: you can use `(Sequence @@ {#, 7} &)[3]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It fails because `Sequence` releases the hold when subjected to the syntax `&`, as `&` is effectively the same as `Function`. For example, the following two are semantically equivalent:

```
#^2 &
Function[#^2]
```

and now replace `#^2` with `Sequence[#, 7]`:

```
Function[Sequence[#, 7]]
```

by which `Sequence` automatically releases the hold as it's supposed to, turning the expression into `Function[#1, 7]` or equivalently `Function[Slot[1], 7]`, a syntax error for `Function`. A workaround that I could think of is just using `Hold` instead of `Sequence` and releasing it later when evaluating:

```
Hold[#, 7] &[3]
(* Hold[3, 7] *)

f[Hold[#, 7] &[3]] // ReleaseHold
(* f[3, 7] *)
```

Answer (score 7):

`##&` is functionally equivalent to `Sequence` in most cases, and does the job here.

[image: ##&[#,7]&[3] -> Sequence[3, 7]]

So long as the argument is not evaluated, `##&[...]` will remain unexpanded, even under heads that do not have `SequenceHold`:

[image: ##& doesn't expand under a head with the HoldAll attribute]

Answer (score 2):

If your Sequence is intended to be used within an enclosing List, then you could use Splice.

```
Splice[{#, 7}] &

(*for example...*)
Splice[{#, 7}] &[3]
(*...returns Splice[{3, 7}]*)

(*...and...*)
{1, (Splice[{#, 7}] &)[8], 3}
(*...returns {1, 8, 7, 3}*)
```

Alternatively, you just need to delay the application of Sequence (as pointed out in the comment by kglr).

```
Sequence @@ {#, 7} &

(*for example...*)
Sequence @@ {#, 7} &[8]
(*...returns Sequence[8, 7]*)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way would be to use [`Construct`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Construct.html):

```
(Construct[Sequence,#,7]&)[3]

(* Sequence[3, 7] *)
```