# Insert a list within another without extra brackets

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a `list1`:

```
list1={{1, -1.1}, {2, -1}, {3, -0.9}, {4, 0}, {10, -0.4}}
```

and `list2`:

```
 list2={{2, -0.6}, {3, -0.6}}
```

and I would like insert `list2` at position `3` in `list1` to get:

```
 {{1, -1.1}, {2, -1}, {2, -0.6}, {3, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {4, 0}, {10, -0.4}}
```

But when I use `Insert[list1, list2, 3]`, I get an extra pair of brackets from 'list2`:

```
{{1, -1.1}, {2, -1}, {{2, -0.6}, {3, -0.6}}, {3, -0.9}, {4, 0}, {10, -0.4}}
```

Is it possible do it without the extra brackets?

Answer (score 10):

- version 12.1 or later

```
list1 = {{1, -1.1}, {2, -1}, {3, -0.9}, {4, 0}, {10, -0.4}};
list2 = {{2, -0.6}, {3, -0.6}};
Insert[list1, Splice@list2, 3]
```

> `{{1, -1.1}, {2, -1}, {2, -0.6}, {3, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {4,  0}, {10, -0.4}}`

- another way.

```
FlattenAt[Insert[list1, list2, 3], 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, but Mathematica shows the error: Splice::string: String expected at position 1 in Splice[{{2,-0.6},{3,-0.6}}].

Comment: @MamMam  Needs version 12.1 or later.  Another way `Join[list1[[1 ;; 2]], list2, list1[[3 ;; -1]]]`

Comment: For versions before 12.1, for simple cases (not this one), you may be able to replace the `Splice@` with `Sequence@@`.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino  I have test `Sequence@@` befor I post the answer. It does not work.

Answer (score 6):

Using Sequence (for older versions of WL without `Splice`):

```
list1 = {{1, -1.1}, {2, -1}, {3, -0.9}, {4, 0}, {10, -0.4}};
list2 = {{2, -0.6}, {3, -0.6}};
Insert[list1, Inactive[Sequence] @@ list2, 3] // Activate
```

Comment: A similar solution: `Insert[list1, \[FormalG] @@ list2, 3] /. \[FormalG] -> Sequence` (`\[FormalG]`  can be replaced with any undefined variable)

Comment: `Unevaluated[Sequence @@ list2]`

Answer (score 5):

The theme of this answer ended up being : "playing with Sequence and MapAt"

- Using `MapAt`, `Apply`, `Sequence` and `Insert`:

  ```
  MapAt[Apply[Sequence], Insert[list1, list2, 3], 3]

  (* {{1, -1.1}, {2, -1}, {2, -0.6}, {3, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {4, 
     0}, {10, -0.4}}  *)
  ```
- Using `MapAt`, `Sequence`, `Apply`, `Join`, `List` and `Function` (no `Insert`):

  ```
  MapAt[Sequence @@ list2~Join~{#} &, list1, 3]

   (* {{1, -1.1}, {2, -1}, {2, -0.6}, {3, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {4, 
    0}, {10, -0.4}} *)
  ```
- Using `MapAt`, `Construct`, `Sequence`, `Apply`, and `Function` (no `Insert`):

  ```
  MapAt[Construct[Sequence, Sequence @@ list2, #] &, list1, 3]

   (* {{1, -1.1}, {2, -1}, {2, -0.6}, {3, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {4, 
    0}, {10, -0.4}} *)
  ```

but

```
 MapAt[Sequence[Sequence @@ list2, #] &, list1, 3]
```

leads to an error

[image: error]

**EDIT**

As mentioned by @att in the comments, the error is due to the fact that `Function` does not have the attribute `SequenceHold`. For workarounds for this issue see the answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/263798/86543). Some of the workarounds from that question including the one by @att applied to this case are:

- Using `MapAt`, `Sequence` (x2), `Apply`, and `Function`(x2) (no `Insert`):

  ```
    MapAt[##&[Sequence @@ list2, #] &, list1, 3]

   (* {{1, -1.1}, {2, -1}, {2, -0.6}, {3, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {4, 
     0}, {10, -0.4}}  *)
  ```
- Using `MapAt`, `Sequence` (x2), `Apply`(x2), and `Function` (no `Insert`):

  ```
   MapAt[Sequence @@ {Sequence @@ list2, #} &, list1, 3]

  (* {{1, -1.1}, {2, -1}, {2, -0.6}, {3, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {4, 
    0}, {10, -0.4}} *)
  ```

Comment: The last one fails because `Function` does not have the `SequenceHold` attribute. You can use `##&` for the outer `Sequence` instead.

Comment: @att nice I saw the other answer where you used that technique. I supposes that it works as it defers the evaluation as with `Sequence @@ {Sequence @@ list2, #} &`

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {{1, -1.1}, {2, -1}, {3, -0.9}, {4, 0}, {10, -0.4}};

b = {{2, -0.6}, {3, -0.6}};
```

Insert at position:

```
p = 3;
```

```
c = Insert[a, b, p];
```

Using `Replace` and `Splice` (new in 12.1)

```
Replace[c, x : {__List} :> Splice[x], {1}]
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[x_ :> Splice[x], p] @ c
```

Using `Take`

```
Catenate[{Take[a, {1, p - 1}], b, Take[a, {p, -1}]}]
```

All produce

> {{1, -1.1}, {2, -1}, {2, -0.6}, {3, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {4,
> 0}, {10, -0.4}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list1 = {{1, -1.1}, {2, -1}, {3, -0.9}, {4, 0}, {10, -0.4}}
list2 = {{2, -0.6}, {3, -0.6}}

TakeList[list1, {2, All}] // Insert[#, list2, 2] & // 
 Map[Apply[Sequence]]

Insert[list1, Hold[Sequence @@ list2], 3] // ReleaseHold

SequenceReplace[list1, {a_, b_, c___} :> 
  Sequence[a, b, Sequence @@ list2, c]]

SequenceSplit[
 Insert[list1, \[Wolf], 3], {\[Wolf]} :> Sequence @@ list2]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
l1 = {{1, -1.1}, {2, -1}, {3, -0.9}, {4, 0}, {10, -0.4}};

l2 = {{2, -0.6}, {3, -0.6}};
```

---

Using `Riffle`:

```
f = Flatten[{#1[[;; 2]], #2, #3[[3 ;;]]}, 1] &;

f @@ Activate@Riffle[Array[Inactive@l1 &, Length@l2], Inactive@l2]
```

> `{{1, -1.1}, {2, -1}, {2, -0.6}, {3, -0.6}, {3, -0.9}, {4, 0}, {10, -0.4}}`